# How to change default SLD in OL 3?

Tags: geoserver, openlayers

I got this layer from geoserver which displays properly on the website:

```
var d2 = new ol.layer.Tile({
    source: new ol.source.TileWMS({
        url: 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/d2/wms',
        params: {'LAYERS': 'd2:d2_sk', 'TILED': false},
        serverType: 'geoserver'
})
});
```

I tried to change SLD:

```
function sliderChange(newval) {
var newSLD = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <StyledLayerDescriptor xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="1.1.0" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/sld http://schemas.opengis.net/sld/1.1.0/StyledLayerDescriptor.xsd" xmlns:se="http://www.opengis.net/se"> <NamedLayer>     <se:Name>d2:d2_sk</se:Name>     <UserStyle>       <se:Name>mujstyl</se:Name>       <se:FeatureTypeStyle>         <se:Rule>           <se:Name>Perfektní</se:Name>           <se:Description>             <se:Title>Perfektní</se:Title>           </se:Description>           <ogc:Filter xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">             <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>               <ogc:PropertyName>stav_' + newval + '</ogc:PropertyName>               <ogc:Literal>1</ogc:Literal>             </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>           </ogc:Filter>           <se:LineSymbolizer>             <se:Stroke>               <se:SvgParameter name="stroke">#00c10e</se:SvgParameter>               <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-width">1</se:SvgParameter>               <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linejoin">bevel</se:SvgParameter>               <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linecap">square</se:SvgParameter>             </se:Stroke>           </se:LineSymbolizer>         </se:Rule>         <se:Rule>           <se:Name>Dobrý</se:Name>           <se:Description>             <se:Title>Dobrý</se:Title>           </se:Description>           <ogc:Filter xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">             <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>               <ogc:PropertyName>stav_' + newval + '</ogc:PropertyName>               <ogc:Literal>2</ogc:Literal>             </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>           </ogc:Filter>           <se:LineSymbolizer>             <se:Stroke>               <se:SvgParameter name="stroke">#ffc813</se:SvgParameter>               <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-width">1</se:SvgParameter>               <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linejoin">bevel</se:SvgParameter>               <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linecap">square</se:SvgParameter>             </se:Stroke>           </se:LineSymbolizer>         </se:Rule>         <se:Rule>           <se:Name>Špatný</se:Name>           <se:Description>             <se:Title>Špatný</se:Title>           </se:Description>           <ogc:Filter xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">             <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>               <ogc:PropertyName>stav_' +  newval + '</ogc:PropertyName>               <ogc:Literal>3</ogc:Literal>             </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>           </ogc:Filter>           <se:LineSymbolizer>             <se:Stroke>               <se:SvgParameter name="stroke">#ff6613</se:SvgParameter>               <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-width">1</se:SvgParameter>               <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linejoin">bevel</se:SvgParameter>               <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linecap">square</se:SvgParameter>             </se:Stroke>           </se:LineSymbolizer>         </se:Rule>         <se:Rule>           <se:Name>Nejhorší</se:Name>           <se:Description>             <se:Title>Nejhorší</se:Title>           </se:Description>           <ogc:Filter xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">             <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>               <ogc:PropertyName>stav_' +  newval + '</ogc:PropertyName>               <ogc:Literal>4</ogc:Literal>             </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>           </ogc:Filter>           <se:LineSymbolizer>             <se:Stroke>               <se:SvgParameter name="stroke">#ef0000</se:SvgParameter>               <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-width">1</se:SvgParameter>               <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linejoin">bevel</se:SvgParameter>               <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linecap">square</se:SvgParameter>             </se:Stroke>           </se:LineSymbolizer>         </se:Rule>       </se:FeatureTypeStyle>     </UserStyle>   </NamedLayer> </StyledLayerDescriptor>';
var source = d2.getSource();
console.log(source);
source.updateParams({STYLES: undefined, SLD_BODY: newSLD});
```

When the function is called then the layer disappears from the map.

I am sure the `newval` returns proper value for the SLD & layer. It seems like a trivial task but I cannot make it work even though I followed a lot of answers on this site.

Comment: Does it work if you use that SLD as a style directly in GeoServer? I.e. make sure your SLD XML is correct first.

Comment: @bartvde I validated it (http://imgur.com/6tqXTik) in Geoserver - No validation errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you specify both LAYERS and SLD_BODY you get in "library mode" and the SLD must be properly setup to work in that case, you need to declare the association with the layer and make the style the default one for such layer, or give a name to the style, and also use STYLES to refer to it.

See:
http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/styling/sld-working.html#library-mode

Comment: to debug try printing out the style and pasting it into GeoServer to check the filter actually matches correctly etc.

Comment: Ah you are right! I had to reload feature types for layer in Geoserver to get the updated columns from PostGIS. The SLD could not catch the column names. Thank you everyone!